# Adding an assembly to the MEF container after composing

Tags: mef

Can I add an assembly to the container after composing? I want to implement on-demand assembly loading. I don't want to use DirectoryCatalog because it takes too long on startup. (there are a lot of assemblies). I want to load specific assembly after an user interaction.

Thank you.

Comment: what time is too long in your case? do you mean compose takes a lot of time? what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes It takes a lot of time. The DirectoryCatalog loads all of the assemblies at startup. I want to load on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

can you post your code what action cause a long load time. but if mef should create your object and this creation takes a lot of time you have no chance to reduce this time? or did i get something wrong?

```
public void Startup
{
    //if this takes a long time, 
    //it would be take a long time even not related assemblies are not in your container
    var myclass = cc.GetExport<MyType>();//or cc.ComposeParts(this);

}
```